# Permanently removing apache2

Tags: apt, apache2

It seems a simple `apt-get remove apache2` does not completely remove `apache2` as I can still see it on one of the processes when running `top`. How does one remove `apache2` completely on his ubuntu server?

It's not removed indeed:

```
~# which apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2
~# whereis apache2
apache2: /usr/sbin/apache2 /etc/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/share/apache2 /usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz
```

But when I do `apt-get remove apache2` again:

```
# apt-get remove apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: run `apt-get purge apache2`. It will remove the all config files.

Comment: I followed this with `apt-get autoremove` and then `sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2`

Answer (score 211, accepted):

`apache2` is a metapackage that just selects other packages. If you installed apache by installing that package, you just need to run this to clean up the automatically selected packages:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

If that doesn't work, you might have installed one of the dependents manually. You can target all the `apache2-` packages from space and nuke the lot:

```
sudo apt remove apache2*
```

For future reference, to find out which package a binary is from, you can run this:

```
dpkg -S `which apache2`
```

I'd expect that to come back with `apache2.2-bin` (at the time of writing).

Comment: also, use --purge if you want the configuration files to be deleted as well: apt-get --purge remove apache2

Comment: The last command outputs `apache2-mpm-prefork: /usr/sbin/apache2`

Comment: @Severus fair enough -- I was just guessing but that makes sense. Yeah I'd just use the wildcard but keen an eye on what it's going to delete. apache2-common is used by some tools that aren't the apache2 httpd so you might need to reinstall some thing after.

Comment: @Oli Removing things with a regex 'apache2*' is dangerous, loads of things end up getting removed

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa It's not "dangerous". `apt-get` (unlike `apt-cache`) limits its searches to names-only so it's not that far-reaching. Everything it captures is Apache or Apache dependent. Check it yourself with `apt-get -s remove apache2*`

Comment: should be sudo apt-get remove apache2.*

Comment: it's too dangerous to run  `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: @Shqear Not really. If the packages you need are only installed to fulfil dependencies on other packages, that's your problem. Mark them manual and autoremove will never remove them. And if you're concerned that something bad might happen, use the `-s` flag to simulate a dry-run before the real thing.

Comment: The Apache is there after server reboot (!), but `E: Unable to locate package apache2.*` on `sudo apt remove apache2.*`... With UBUNTU 20 LTS only `sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2-bin apache2.2-common` is working.

Comment: This just removed dokku. Fortunately not production but beware, autoremove is absolutely dangerous. If this was production I would be absolutely F(*&#%'d right now.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, this doesn't work and removes 0 packages.

Comment: @MikeB I've changed the command to `apt remove apache2*`. This used to us a "regular expression" and now seems to use a glob.

Answer (score 192):

Follow these steps to remove the `apache2` service using `Terminal`:

1. First stop the apache2 service if it is running with: `sudo service apache2 stop`
2. Now remove and cleanup all the apache2 packages with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
   //or 
   sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2-bin apache2.2-common
   ```
3. Finally, run `sudo apt-get autoremove` just in case any other cleanup in needed

You can do the following two tests to confirm apache has been removed:

1. `which apache2` - should return a blank line
2. `sudo service apache2 start` - should return `apache2: unrecognized service`

Comment: sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2-bin apache2.2-common

Comment: works perfect for me

Comment: When I run *which apache2* it reports */usr/sbin/apache2*.  Should that someone be deleted before reinstalling?

Comment: purging apache2-bin should remove /usr/sbin/apache2

Answer (score 86):

A very simple and straightforward way that worked for me is as follows:

1. Stop `apache2`.

   ```
   sudo service apache2 stop
   ```
2. Uninstall Apache2 and its dependent packages.

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
   ```
3. Use `autoremove` option to get rid of other dependencies.

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
4. Check whether there are any configuration files that have not been removed.

   ```
   whereis apache2
   ```
5. If you get a response as follows `apache2: /etc/apache2` remove the directory and existing configuration files.

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
   ```

<sub>Source: [How to uninstall and remove Apache2 on Ubuntu or Debian](https://web.archive.org/web/20181126010942/http://xmodulo.com/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-apache2-on-ubuntu-debian.html) by Dan Nanni</sub>

Comment: For me it was: sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2-bin apache2.2-common

Answer (score 8):

**Remove apache2 from the Ubuntu**

[image]

To remove totally from your **localhost**

1st check the current status using

```
service apache2 status
```

if it's **active (running)**
write next

```
sudo apt remove apache2*
```

Say yes using `y`.

Answer (score 8):

For a Debian based OS, like Ubuntu, use:

```
sudo apt remove --purge apache2
sudo apt autoremove -y
```

Comment: or you can just use this `sudo apt remove apache2`

Answer (score 5):

First check if you are using right package name, IMO correct package name is : `apache2.x-common`

If you want to completely remove the package including config files then try:

```
    dpkg --purge apache2.2-common
```

Answer (score 4):

Take time to check if you are using the different package `apache2.2-bin` for Ubuntu 16.04 the latest is `apache2.4-bin`

`sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.4-bin apache2.4-common`

Answer (score 3):

I tried the other answers here but this is the most complete solution I have found which worked for me:

```
$ sudo service apache2 stop
$ sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

The output of the below command will provide you with information the installed package software, version, architecture and short description about the package. grep command is used to find the apache package

```
$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep apache | cut -f 1
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge <package name from the previous command output>
$ sudo whereis apache
$ sudo rm -rf <directory/file path from the previous command output>
```

see http://www.xavierdilipkumar.com/post/how-to-uninstall-php-apache-and-mysql-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Use this to delete installation and its dependencies. It will also reload the firewall

```
sudo dpkg --purge apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

These commands will completely remove Apache2, all its configs, logs and www files.

```bash
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt purge apache2
sudo apt purge apache2-utils
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apache2
sudo rm -rf /var/log/apache2
```

And if you want to remove all www files too,

```bash
sudo rm -rf /var/www/html
```

**WARNING**: `sudo rm -rf /var/www/html` will delete all files in your `/var/www/html` directory, make sure you don't have anything important there!!!

Comment: You should not add the last command. The question is how to remove apache2, not the files. Someone might copy and paste all the commands without reading your warning (I was going to do the same). That will be a big disaster. So please remove the last command.

Comment: This is why the warning is there, and now you comment.