# how to remove apache2?

Tags: server, apache2

Well i installed apache2 by typing

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

now i am tring to uninstall apache2 by this command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove apache2
```

Well my apache2 is still running. And when i stop it vie typing

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

it stops, and i can also start it typing

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Whats the point of auto remove anyway? and how to remove apache2 ?

Answer (score 14):

Try the following command to uninstall and remove configuration files.
You need to stop the apache service **BEFORE** you uninstall.

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2*
```

If you have the service running but not installed (according to apt), stop the service and reinstall, then issue the command above.

Answer (score 3):

You want `remove` or `purge`, not `autoremove` so:

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

`purge` will attempt to remove configuration as well as the installed files (can be dangerous if you're planning on reinstalling).

`autoremove` is just there to remove automatically installed but now not currently required dependencies. So after you remove Apache, a `sudo apt-get autoremove` will probably remove some of the things that only Apache needed.

Comment: `nihan@heel:~/dev/app/website$ sudo apt-get remove apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed`
But i can start and stop it!

Comment: @KatrinaMcmahon: because it will be removed only when you restart your system. Do it once and check whether it is removed completely or not?

Comment: No, it's because the binary is actually in a dependency package (`apache2-mpm-prefork`) so an autoremove after removing `apache2` should do the trick. This all sounds familiar because I've already answered this elsewhere. That's [the question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176964/permanently-removing-apache2) I've closed this one against.

Comment: +1 for answering the other parts of the question