# Cannot get Apache2 to run

Tags: server, apache2

I was having some trouble with Apache2 and reading the web it seemed in uninstall reinstall should sort the issue.

I did that following this [link.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176964/permanently-removing-apache2)

I've now reinstalled apache but as soon as I run `service apache2 status` I get the following

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2018-05-29 16:41:31 UTC; 2min 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 19421 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19412 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What it says when you run `sudo systemctl start apache2.service`?

Comment: Nothing, blank line.  But it isn't running

Comment: How did you verify that it is not running?

Comment: `service apache2 status`