# Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

Tags: server

Running docker, I get this port issue:

```
ERROR: for mmp_php_1  Cannot start service php: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mmp_php_1 (80f0277f963830426b07e4ae461b8533864822fceb67263a78c27b4ae91d87f5): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mmp_php_1 (80f0277f963830426b07e4ae461b8533864822fceb67263a78c27b4ae91d87f5): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Then I check the ports and it appears something is using 80.

```
timothy@13-9360:~/Public/pub/mmp$ ps -eaf | grep 1380
root      1380     2  0 Nov04 ?        00:00:00 [hci0]
timothy  20779  9201  0 08:34 pts/18   00:00:00 grep --color=auto 1380
timothy@13-9360:~/Public/pub/mmp$ netstat -tlnp | grep 80
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

How do I kill whatever process is running here so I can use port 80 again?

My localhost is the apache landing page atm which is weird because I've removed apache from my computer. Not sure why that's happening either.

```
sudo netstat -tlnp

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58347           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1029/rpc.mountd 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2591/vino-server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16215/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44814           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1019/rpcbind    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1089/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3036/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46357           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1029/rpc.mountd 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20431/cupsd     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29754         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1268/vpnagentd  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2696/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16215/java      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42622           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1029/rpc.mountd 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2696/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2696/dropbox    
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      18276/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      2591/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 :::59533                :::*                    LISTEN      1029/rpc.mountd 
tcp6       0      0 :::42991                :::*                    LISTEN      1029/rpc.mountd 
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1019/rpcbind    
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      18412/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1089/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      20431/cupsd     
tcp6       0      0 :::15672                :::*                    LISTEN      18260/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::47673                :::*                    LISTEN      1029/rpc.mountd 
tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*                    LISTEN      2696/dropbox    
tcp6       0      0 :::35324                :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Shouldn't i be able to just change the port like you were saying.

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
     - ./www:/var/www/html:delegated
     - ./configs:/configs
    links:
     - db:db
     - redis:redis
     - rabbit:rabbit
     - elasticsearch:elasticsearch
    ports:
     -  "80:80"
     -  "443:443"
    extra_hosts:
     -  "localhost.local:127.0.0.1"
    environment:
     - CONFIG__DEFAULT__CATALOG__SEARCH__ELASTICSEARCH_SERVER_HOSTNAME=elasticsearch
  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
```

Comment: Hi, use `sudo`, `sudo netstat -tlnp` to display also the process names.

Comment: okay.. i will post above. it appears nginx -g daemo... maybe?

Comment: Do you run a website or something with NGINX here?  Regarding the Apache landing page and not NGINX, see [this answer I wrote](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074035/how-can-i-stop-apache2-on-ubuntu-18-04/1074043#1074043) - you don't have Apache, you have nginx, but this answer explains why you're seeing the Apache landing page.  Note also that as a user-space individual, you can't directly bind to port 80.  Run your proxy on 8080.

Comment: ahh.. yes that makes more sense why i was seeing the page... i think that fixed that issue but now i'm encountering a new issue.  ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: That sounds like a Docker container issue with that specific docker instance.  Without knowing what Docker image you're launching that could be a lot harder to debug.

Comment: I changed it back and now it's going back to the original problem... i posted my docker yml file above.... i feel like i've changed the port before an it's worked like you were saying...

Comment: or what exactly happens when i use expose instead of ports? @Thomas Ward

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once.

Another process was bound to port 80.

I had to find the culprit. I used netstat to find which process was using port 80.

You might need to install a package that includes *netstat*: **net-tools**

```
sudo apt install net-tools -y
```

Once installed, *netstat* was installed, proceeded with command

```
sudo netstat -tlnp
```

What I got was something similar to this :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4227/httpd
```

So process *httpd* with ID 4227 was using port 80.
I opened htop, hit F3 to enable search, typed in httpd and found out that nextcloud (a file storage cloud server) was the parent process using httpd (a web page server).

What you do next however, is up to you. You might want to change the ports they use and then forward them internally. Or maybe just remove the app using that port or disabling it temporarily.

I was in the process of installing Docker to containerise my existing servers/services, etc. so I removed the Nextcloud snap, restarted Docker.

```
sudo snap remove nextcloud
```

To restart docker, I initally tried `sudo systemctl restart docker`
but realised that was not the name of the service because it was a Snap docker.

To find the name of the service I would have to sift through systemctl statuses:

```
sudo systemctl status | grep docker
```

and found out the service name was `snap.docker.dockerd.service`

To restart it, I used `sudo systemctl restart snap.docker.dockerd.service`

Then I tried my docker command again, and the error was gone.