# removed apache and its config file from ubuntu, browser still shows default page

Tags: apache2

I have removed apache from my ubuntu 18.04 including all its config files using `apt purge apache2`. Browser still show default page on doing localhost:80. Please explain ?

Comment: Try clearing temporary data like cache, cookie or try in incognito/private browsing

Comment: Find out which process is serving port 80: `sudo lsof -i tcp:80`, and kill it.

Comment: Can you share the command you used to remove Apache?  It's possible it wasn't removed correctly.

Comment: @waltinator: this doesn't show any process running, but browser still serves local apache page, after restarting the browser.

Comment: @thomasrutter:  apt purge apache2

Comment: @Kulfy: yes, in incognito, its not  directing to default apahce page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently removing apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176964/permanently-removing-apache2)

Comment: @Rahul in that case it is due to temporary data like cookies and cache. Go to browser settings and clear them and then try again

Answer (score 4):

If you run this command and it shows a running Apache2 server, you still have a web server installed:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

It's also possible you have a different web server installed and running, such as `lighttpd` or `nginx`. Likewise you can check if they are running:

```
sudo service lighttpd status
sudo service nginx status
```

You can also try removing all of the packages associated with them this way:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service lighttpd stop
sudo service nginx stop
sudo apt remove apache2 apache2-bin
sudo apt remove lighttpd
sudo apt remove nginx
```

If for some reason you *still* have a HTTP server running consider looking at:

```
which apache2
which lighttpd
which nginx
```

To see if any files are located in `/usr/local` or `/opt` - in which case you have to delete them manually.

You can also find which command specifically is using port 80 using this:

```
sudo netstat -plnt | grep ':80'
```

Answer (score 3):

Even after uninstalling apache2 it kept showing
the default page. I tried rebooting, but nothing worked,
until I cleared the cache and cookies of the Browser

So, try and **clear your browser's cache & cookies**.

Comment: dude you just saved me some time!